# Power BI Desktop Matrix Visualization - Columns within a column

Tags: matrix, powerbi

[image: From Excel]

The above image is from an excel file. I would like to recreate that in Power BI Desktop. By using the Matrix Visualization in Power BI Desktop I did only manage to create this:

[image: Power BI Desktop Matrix Visualization]

Another problem is that I can't add the Shipped Date Year again since it is already added.

Thanks.

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to get the same data is by adding `Records` twice to the `Values`, once as a Sum and once as an Average. The layout will be slightly different though:

[image: Rows ShipVia, Columns Year, Values Records twice]

To get the original layout you had with PowerBI I suspect you need to jump through quite some hoops, and modify your data sets.

Alternatively, Why make things hard? Just drop in two matrixes:

[image: Two separate matrices]